# 500 Error: TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

I have enabled my GitLab server to use the GitLab registry which is hosted on another server. It was installed from source.

The GitLab admin console indicates that the registry is enabled and active, however when I try to access the registry a 500 error is thrown.

The production logs show the following

```
    Started GET "/root/Test/container_registry" for 10.188.144.64 at 2016-12-01 11:42:00 +0000
Processing by Projects::ContainerRegistryController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"namespace_id"=>"root", "project_id"=>"Test"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 61ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)

TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
  lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:20:in `read'
  lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:20:in `key_data'
  lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:24:in `key'
  lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:28:in `public_key'
  lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:33:in `kid'
  lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:12:in `encoded'
  app/services/auth/container_registry_authentication_service.rb:30:in `full_access_token'
  app/models/project.rb:463:in `container_registry_repository'
  app/controllers/projects/container_registry_controller.rb:28:in `container_registry_repository'
  app/controllers/projects/container_registry_controller.rb:8:in `index'
  lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:15:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:16:in `call'
```

Any advice or guidance with fixing this would be welcome! 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version are you running? A 500 error is almost always indicative of a bug. I would [open an issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/new).

Comment: I'm running version 8.14.1. Thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: Please post a link here for future readers if you do.

Comment: Link to the issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/25262#note_19356548

Comment: New link to issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/25262#note_19356548